# Rust 'use of moved value' error when passing value into Enum variant

Tags: rust, enums, ownership

I am very new to Rust (just a couple of days). Of course, I am already getting stuck with the concept of ownership.

I have a rather lengthy problem, so here are all the relevant declarations I used:

```rust
pub struct ThePrimaryStruct<'a> {
    frames: Vec<Frame<'a>>,
    stack: Vec<Object<'a>>,
    ip: usize
}

pub struct FunctionObject<'a> {
    pub min_arity: i32,
    pub max_arity: i32,
    pub chunk: Chunk<'a>,
    pub name: &'a str,
}

pub struct Frame<'a> {
    pub function: FunctionObject<'a>,
    // ... other struct members
}

pub struct Chunk<'a> {
    pub codes: Vec<OpCode>, // OpCode is an enum
    pub locations: Vec<(i64, i64)>,
    pub constants: Vec<Object<'a>>
}

pub enum Object<'a> {
    Function(FunctionObject<'a>),
    // Other enum variants
}
```

The above code is not the problem. The problem arises when I implement the following method for `ThePrimaryStruct`:

```rust
pub(crate) fn the_function(&mut self, source: &'a str) -> SomeResult {
    // `Compiler::compile()` returns a FunctionObject struct.
    let func: FunctionObject = Compiler::compile(source);

    // The enum variant `Object::Function` takes ownership of `func`
    // The code works fine up until this point.
    self.stack.push(Object::Function(func));

    self.frames.push(Frame {
        // The struct member `function` should have the
        // exact same value as the one we just pushed into
        // the `self.stack` vector.
        function: func, // <---- Source of conflict
        // ... other struct members
    });

    self.run() // self.run() returns `SomeResult`
}
```

Running this results in the error:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `func`
   |
37 |         let func: FunctionObject = Compiler::compile(source);
   |             ---- move occurs because `func` has type `FunctionObject<'_>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
40 |         self.stack.push(Object::Function(func));
   |                                          ---- value moved here
...
44 |             function: func,
   |                       ^^^^ value used here after move
```

I understand why this error occurs (or at least I think I understand): The `Object::Function` variant takes ownership of `func`, which is then dropped from memory when we are done pushing the object into `self.stack`. This then creates a conflict with the initialization of the `Frame` struct because I am trying to use a value that no longer exists.

I have tried implementing the `Copy` trait for the struct `FunctionObject`, but that creates even more problems because `FunctionObject` has a member of type `Chunk<'a>` which itself has vector members.

**EDIT:**
Cloning definitely solves the problem. However, by cloning the `FunctionObject` I would be duplicating the data inside the `chunk` which could be of an arbitrarily long size. Referencing the `FunctionObject` in both the `stack` with `Object::Function(&func)` and in the `frame` with `Frame { function: &func, ... }` then results in a `'func' does not live long enough` error.

Is there something fundamentally wrong with what I am trying to do?

Comment: you can `#[derive(Clone)]` and clone it. If the same `func` is supposed to be *shared*, then you have a [self-referential struct problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct), and you might want to look into reference counted pointers.

Comment: You seem to have a `FunctionObject` that you want to store both in `stack` and `frame`. Maybe a better solution is to reference the `FunctionObject` instead in `stack` and `frame`, or if that is not possible, simplify `FunctionObject` to itself contain a reference to non-copiable data and then be trivially copiable.

Comment: @Emoun I have tried passing the reference to both the `stack` and the `frame` but that results in the error `'func' does not live long enough.` Could you explain what you mean by "simplify FunctionObject to itself contain a reference to non-copiable data and then be trivially copiable"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a `FunctionObject` that you want to store both in `stack` and `frame`.
A better solution might be to not store the `FunctionObject` directly on the stack and frame, but use [smart pointers](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-00-smart-pointers.html) instead.

I will show you a solution using `Rc`, however, you seem to be making a compiler, so you might want a different data structure to store your function objects in, like an [arena](https://manishearth.github.io/blog/2021/03/15/arenas-in-rust/#whats-an-arena).

The following code includes only the changes I made to your original, but you can also have a look [on the playground where I got it to compile](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ea085ea6768d7d24b95ae87ceeb6fe24):

```rust
pub struct Frame<'a> {
    pub function: std::rc::Rc<FunctionObject<'a>>,
    // ... other struct members
}

pub enum Object<'a> {
    Function(std::rc::Rc<FunctionObject<'a>>),
    // Other enum variants
}

pub(crate) fn the_function(&mut self, source: &'a str) -> SomeResult {
    // `Compiler::compile()` returns a FunctionObject struct.
    let func: FunctionObject = Compiler::compile(source);
    let func = std::rc::Rc::new(func);
    
    
    // The enum variant `Object::Function` takes ownership of `func`
    // The code works fine up until this point.
    self.stack.push(Object::Function(func.clone()));

    self.frames.push(Frame {
        // The struct member `function` should have the
        // exact same value as the one we just pushed into
        // the `self.stack` vector.
        function: func, // <---- No longer source of conflict
        // ... other struct members
    });

    self.run() // self.run() returns `SomeResult`
}
```

`Rc` manages an object by reference counting.
When the last `Rc` is dropped, the value (`FunctionObject`) will also be dropped.
Using `.clone()` on `func` makes a copy of the reference and increments the count, but doesn't copy the underlying object.

Comment: Thank you! I've only been playing with rust for a couple of days and was not aware of smart pointers or how they work. I will definitely read up on that.